# Weird behaviour with multiple form tags on page

Tags: asp.net, multiple-forms

I am seeing something weird and I don't know it works like that.

I have a ASP.NET page based on a template which has a form with runat="server tag. On this page, I have another form which is client-side so it doesn't have a runat="server" tag. This form contains an action attribute with a URL pointing to a third party website. 
On clicking the submit button of this form, the form never goes through and the page just sits like that.

If I add another  tag on this page right above my  tag, then I can submit the form to the action URL. 
My question is why does the form not submit unless I put an additional empty  tag in there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide some code to assist us in helping you!

Answer (score 1):

You [cannot nest HTML FORMS](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html)

> Every form must be enclosed within a FORM element. There can be several forms in a single document, but the FORM element can't be nested.

See if [PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) will solve your need in ASP.Net *Web Forms*.

Other than that, you can certainly do ASP.Net Razor so you get out of the "single FORM web page model" of ASP.Net *Web Forms*.